# Swift 3 Alamofire is sometimes going to failure block

Tags: swift, response, alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(NEWS_FEED_URL).responseJSON { response in
        guard let newsResponse = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] else{
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        print("JSON: \(newsResponse)")
```

This is my alamofire code to get response from server. Most of the time it is working fine but sometime it goes failure and print Error. Even if I paste print("JSON:", newsResponse) in failure block it shows the response but it is not going to the success block. I also print the status code once. Its giving me 200. My Internet is working good, the related url is giving response in postman. But sometimes it is not working why?

Comment: When it is failing then your response is not `[[String:String]]` add the response here when it is failing

Comment: That's certainly what is saying NiravD. It's failing because the cast is not working. Print response in that case to see what should be done.

Comment: Response is like: [{key:value},{key:value},{key:value}]

Comment: And are you sure that the value are all String? Can't it be a Int? Use `as? [[String:Any]]` instead?

Comment: [
  {
    "title": "Trump's pointing",
    "link": "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=",
    "category": "World",
    "pubDate": "Tue, 09 May 2017",
    "description": "Washington PostTrump&#39;s pointing ",
    "image": "//t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:"
  }] ----------------- This is the response.

Comment: If that's the real response, then you JSON is not valid. It has an extra `;`.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Yes there is extra ; inside description value but it is inside " ". Does that matter? Ex: [{"title": "title here", "description":"description value here;"}]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method**

```
   func apiRequest(method:String, urlMethod:String, parametersDictionary:NSMutableDictionary, success:@escaping successDictionaryBlock, failure: @escaping failBlockErrorMessage){
            let requestUrl = "Request URL"


            Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .post, parameters: (parametersDictionary as NSDictionary) as? Parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                print(requestUrl)

                if(response.result.error == nil){

                    if((response.response?.statusCode)! < 500){

                        if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){

                            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                                print(JSON)
                                let dict = JSON as! NSDictionary
                                let status :Bool = dict["status"] as! Bool

                                if(status){
                                    success(dict)
                                }else{
                                    failure(dict["message"] as! String)
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            failure("Something went wrong please try again")
                        }
                    }else{
                         failure("Something went wrong please try again")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```